# Adding spaces and new lines in printing the content of vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

A have a small question. How can I add the spaces and new line signs, so that the effect looks like that?

```
ACCT
 CCTG
  CTGA
```

etc.

```
vector<string>::reverse_iterator it;
   for( it=vec.rbegin(); it!=vec.rend(); ++it )
   {

      cout<<*it;
      cout<<endl;
      cout<<" ";

   }
```

I've tried this way, but the shift is only after first element, like that:

```
ACCT
 CCTG
CTGA
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: What exactly do you want based on what input? Do you want to align on CT or do you want to add an additional space per line or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this one:

```
std::string space = "";

for(auto it = vec.rbegin(); it != vec.rend(); ++it ) {
    std::cout << space << *it << std::endl;
    space += " ";
}
```

This one doesn't output the final spaces on a new line.

Comment: Is it? Why declare the iterator outside the scope of the `for`?

Answer (score 5):

```
vector<string>::reverse_iterator it;
   string space="";
   for( it=vec.rbegin(); it!=vec.rend(); ++it )
   {

      cout<<*it;
      cout<<endl;
      space += " ";
      cout<<space;

   }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
size_t spaces = 0;
for (auto it = vec.rbegin(); it != vec.rend(); ++it)
    cout << string(spaces++, ' ') << *it << '\n';
```