# Concatenation of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector

In vector c++, I have strings, for example :
ACTT CTTG TTGA TG TGA GAG, as you can see, they superpose

```
ACTT
 CTTG
  TTGA
   TG
    GAG
```

So in the alignment we can see

```
ACTTGAG
```

I want to concatenate them as you can see above and put to another vector. I've tried use substring function, but it doesn't work...

Comment: You want to build the shortest string for which each and every one of those strings is a substring?

Comment: what do you mean 'it doesn't work'? I use substr all the time and it work fine for me..

Comment: What doesn't work?  What have you tried?

Comment: I think you should take a look at these things http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_suffix_tree
Traversing the trie may help you yield what you want

Comment: when I use substring, I dont know how to use it more globally for strings, when they length are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you still use the same code as [the last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115288/adding-spaces-and-new-lines-in-printing-the-content-of-vector) you might want to consider using the first index you have in your element (`it[0]`). You could add this result to a string and print it.

Use:

```
std::string space = "";
std::string result = "";
auto end = vec.rend();

for(auto it = vec.rbegin(); it != vec.rend(); ++it ) {
    if (it == end - 1) {
        result += *it;
    }
    else {
        result += it[0];
    }        

    std::cout << space << *it << std::endl;
    space += " ";
}
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Comment: yes, but when I use substring in that and some of the strings are shorter I don't know how to concatenate them this way

Comment: @AirelleJab Updated answer with a better example

Comment: thanks a lot, but I have one more question - I have a compilation problem,because there is no match for operator "+=" in result+=it, operator "+" is also unavaliable

Comment: @AirelleJab My bad I made a typo :) the first '+= it;' should be: '+= *it;'. Working example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d7b8b2149e0b669

Comment: unfortunately, it prints all the strings, one after one :(

Comment: Did you check the example I linked?

Comment: yes, I copied it, but replaced auto by if (it == vec.rend() - 1)

Comment: @AirelleJab if you copy this code provided in the answer it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly simple algorithm to overlap two strings:

```
#include <string>

std::string overlap(std::string first, std::string const & second)
{
    std::size_t pos = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < first.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (first.compare(first.size() - i, i, second, 0, i) == 0)
        {
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    first.append(second, pos, second.npos);
    return first;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::string result = overlap("abcde", "defgh");
```

And to overlap a whole range, use `std::accumulate`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> strings = {"abc", "def", "fegh", "ghq"};
  std::cout << std::accumulate(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::string(), overlap) << std::endl;
}
```